# Linking python to html

Tags: python, html

I'm trying to  use python as a back end for my website, I am stuck with linking up python to HTML. 
I tried:

```html
 <link src="back.py" rel="python" type="text/python"/>
```

That didn't work, I tried to look it up but no luck. Any ideas?

Comment: you need a server ... in order to just call a python script you will need the cgi plugin for whatever you use as your server ... usually people tend to run websites in python using wsgi, but that doesnt really let you just call a script like that even then

Answer (score 0):

`$ pip install flask`

**/src/templates/file.html**

```
<div id="stuff">asd</div>
<script>
  fetch("/call_me_later.py").then(r=>r.text()).then(text=>
    {
     document.getElementById("stuff").innerText = text
    }
  )
</script>
```

**/src/app.py**

```
import flask
app = flask.Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
@app.route("/index.html")
def index_route():
    return flask.render_template("file.html")

@app.route("/call_me_later.py")
def some_other_view():
    return "This text was returned from python!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

to run it

```
cd src
python app.py
```

this will create a developement server you can work with, once you learn enough you would deploy it with apache or nginx typically

Comment: this code does not work for some reason. im not sure

Comment: I had some typos ... https://repl.it/@JoranBeasley/Python-Flask-Website#main.py

Answer (score 0):

**Hello World” in HTML using Python**

One of the more powerful ideas in computer science is that a file that seems to contain code from one perspective can be seen as data from another. It is possible, in other words, to write programs that manipulate other programs. What we’re going to do next is create an HTML file that says “Hello World!” using Python. We will do this by storing HTML tags in a multiline Python string and saving the contents to a new file. This file will be saved with an .html extension rather than a .txt extension.

```
# write-html.py

    f = open('helloworld.html','wb')

    message = """<html>
    <head></head>
    <body><p>Hello World!</p></body>
    </html>"""

    f.write(message)
    f.close()
```